# Why is this integer considered a float?

Tags: php, types

I have created the following script for determining which page numbers to display for navigation on my website.

```
// query the database

$statement = $connect->prepare("SELECT COUNT(report_number) FROM reports");
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$rowCount = $result["COUNT(report_number)"];
$pgCount = ceil($rowCount / 10);


// fetch the corresponding entries from the database

if (!isset($pgParamArray["page"]) || $pgParamArray["page"] === $pgCount) {
  $pgParamArray["page"] = $pgCount;
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM reports ORDER BY report_number DESC LIMIT 10";
} elseif (isset($pgParamArray["page"])) {
  $offset = ($pgCount - $pgParamArray["page"]) * 10;
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM reports ORDER BY report_number DESC LIMIT " . $offset . ",10";
}


// calculate and display the appropriate page numbers

$upperDiff = $pgCount - $pgParamArray["page"];
$lowerDiff = $pgParamArray["page"] - 1;

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {

  $pgNo = 0;

  if ($pgParamArray["page"]+2 <= $pgCount && $pgParamArray["page"]-2 >= 1) {
    $pgNo = $pgParamArray["page"] + ($i - 2);
  } elseif ($pgCount < 5) {
    $pgNo = $i+1 <= $pgCount ? $i+1 : 0;
  } elseif ($upperDiff < $lowerDiff && $upperDiff < 2 && $upperDiff >= 0) {
    $pgNo = ($pgCount - 4) + $i;
  } elseif ($lowerDiff < $upperDiff && $lowerDiff < 2 && $lowerDiff >= 0) {
    $pgNo = $i + 1;
  } else {
    $pgNo = ($pgCount - 4) + $i;
  }

  if ($pgNo > 0) {
    if ($pgNo !== $pgParamArray["page"]) {
      $pgNoArray[] = ""
        . "<li><div><a href='http://www.somewebsite.com/index.php/?page="
        . $pgNo
        . "'>"
        . $pgNo
        . "</a></div></li>";
    } else {
      $pgNoArray[] = ""
        . "<li><div style='background:#333'>"
        . $pgNo
        . "</div></li>";
    }
  }
}
```

When I set `$pgParamArray["page"] = $pgCount = ceil($rowCount/10)`, I have noticed that the foremost variable is still treated as a float. My question is **why is `$pgParamArray["page"]` of type float even though `ceil($rowCount/10)` obviously returns an integer?**

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes exist for this - it seems a reasonable question. Even though the answer is simple, if you don't know the answer, it's perplexing.

Comment: @corsiKa i think i have people following me around down voting my questions/answers for whatever reason. it's a legit question since the answer is counter-intuitive, and sure i could've checked the documentation, but didn't precisely because the "answer" is counter-intuitive. i find it amusing that they have an issue with my question, but not the answer lol. anyways, thanks for your concern nonetheless <3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP's `ceil` [returns a float](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) according to their documentation.

Their rationale:

> value rounded up to the next highest integer. The return value of ceil() is still of type float as the value range of float is usually bigger than that of integer.

This isn't just PHP that does this - [C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/ceil/) and [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil(double)) both return floating point values for their ceiling functions.

Comment: even though it returns an integer. that's so effing bizarre and counter-intuitive. as if rounding a float up would exceed the value range of integers. wouldn't there be only a single case in which that would be true? -.-a

Comment: =) I updated my answer - this is standard across multiple languages.

Comment: oh man i simply do not understand that rationale. logically, shouldn't there be only one case in which converting a float to an integer would exceed the value range of type integer?

Comment: @Anthony I think the rationale is that you have a type going in, you're going to want to use the same type coming out - I could be wrong.

Comment: i guess that would make sense. it's just that the data doesn't match the description of the data, which can lead to confusion, especially amongst n00bies like myself. it was even causing me issues for a moment until i checked the data type and changed the `!==` to `!=`